# Sign v. sign off

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

When you finish your letter by writing, for instance, "Love, John", do you "sign" your letter or "sign off"? Both seem to fit, semantically speaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sign off:

> to announce the end of something (such as a message or broadcast) [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sign%20off)

sign:

> write one's name on (a letter, card, document, etc.) to identify oneself as the writer or sender [Source](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sign)

"sign off" is used for **ending** the letter with a sentence or summary, and "sign" is for writing your name/signature to show who you are. In this case - "love, john" - "sign" is correct.